# Saving multiple Athena queries using a template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena

Here is a template that works correctly and saves a query to Athena. But how do I save more than 1 query in a single template?

```json
{
  "Resources": {
    "AthenaNamedQuery": {
      "Type": "AWS::Athena::NamedQuery",
      "Properties": {
        "Database": "swfnetadata",
        "Description": "A query that selects all aggregated data",
        "Name": "MostExpensiveWorkflow",
        "QueryString": "SELECT workflowname, AVG(activitytaskstarted) AS AverageWorkflow FROM swfmetadata WHERE year='17' AND GROUP BY workflowname ORDER BY AverageWorkflow DESC LIMIT 10"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just stick another resource in the template:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "AthenaNamedQuery": {
      "Type": "AWS::Athena::NamedQuery",
      "Properties": {
        "Database": "swfnetadata",
        "Description": "A query that selects all aggregated data",
        "Name": "MostExpensiveWorkflow",
        "QueryString": "SELECT workflowname, AVG(activitytaskstarted) AS AverageWorkflow FROM swfmetadata WHERE year='17' AND GROUP BY workflowname ORDER BY AverageWorkflow DESC LIMIT 10"
      }
    },
  "AnotherAthenaNamedQuery": {
      "Type": "AWS::Athena::NamedQuery",
      "Properties": {
        "Database": "swfnetadata",
        "Description": "Another query",
        "Name": "AnotherQuery",
        "QueryString": "SELECT 1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```